# $\int \frac{dx}{cosh^2x \sqrt{sech^2x+1}}$

Tags: integration

$\int \frac{dx}{cosh^2x \sqrt{sech^2x+1}}$

I tried weierstrass substitution for hyperbolic functions and got nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let $u=\tanh x$, you will end up with
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-u^2}}\,du,
$$
which I assume you can handle.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, but how to choose wisely ?

I learned that the key for the trigonometric and hyperbolic integration is the half-angle substitution. but what about this case ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Some formulas for the hypergeometric functions are good to know (compare with trigonometric ones): $D\tanh x=1/\cosh^2x$ is one of them. Then, we try to make this work with the square root, $$\text{sech}^2x+1=\frac{\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2x}{\cosh^2x}+1=2-\tanh^2x.$$ I don't claim that this is the first try one makes, but when it is done, it is done...